# I am trying to generate dns-sd query for _universal._sub._ipp.tcp.local, is there a way to request sub query

Tags: bonjour, airprint, mdns, dns-sd

I am trying to generate dns-sd query for `_universal._sub._ipp.tcp.local`, is there a way to request subquery.

```
ciscos-Mac-mini:~ cisco$ dns-sd -Z _ipps._tcp,_universal
Browsing for _ipps._tcp,_universal                      
DATE: ---Thu 20 Sep 2018---                             
12:02:43.929  ...STARTING...

ciscos-Mac-mini:~ cisco$ dns-sd -B _universal._sub._ipps._tcp.local     
Browsing for _universal._sub._ipps._tcp.local                           
DNSService call failed -65540  

ciscos-Mac-mini:~ cisco$ dns-sd -Z _ipps._tcp                
Browsing for _ipps._tcp                                      
DATE: ---Thu 20 Sep 2018---                                  
12:03:57.460  ...STARTING...
```

However, there is a response to the above request.

Is there any way to send a query out for subtype.